# Show that: $\inf(A) = -\sup(-A)$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Given $ A\subseteq \mathbb R$ and $A\neq \emptyset  $, (that is, $A$ has a lower bound) and $ -A=\{ x|-x \in A\}$. Show that: $\inf(A) = -\sup(-A)$

Hi,  I need help for proof this limit, which could be used arguments or results. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Don't know what you have tried, but I would suggest first looking at examples where $A$ is finite and small (so your $\inf$ and $\sup$ become $\min$ and $\max$), and then at examples where $A$ is bounded.

Comment: $A \not \empty$ does not imply that $A$ has a lower bound!

Answer (score 2):

Prove the equivalent statement $-\inf A = \sup(-A)$ by showing that $-\inf A$ is an upper bound of $-A$ and if $p \lt -\inf A$ then $p$ is not an upper bound of $-A$.